# Changing the order of private keys passed via ssh login

Tags: linux, ssh, security

A server was set to accept three login attempts. The `ssh` system is checking three identity files before choosing the correct one.

The ssh command is as follows:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/username username@xx.xx.xx.xxx -v
```

The three identity files are as follows:

```
debug2: key: /path/to/.ssh/identity1 
debug2: key: /path/to/.ssh/identity2
debug2: key: /path/to/.ssh/identity3 
debug2: key: /path/to/.ssh/username
```

How can I remove the three incorrect identity files? I have already tried deleting them from the directory, also I tried updating `~/.ssh/config`  as follows:

```
Host xx.xx.xx.xxx  
User username  
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/username
```

How can I get have `ssh` to use the correct identity file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the identity file is listed

```
ssh-add -l
```

If not, add it

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/username
```

Was then able to select the proper identity file

Comment: Was the reason for the problem that the other identities had been loaded by ssh-agent?

Comment: @HaukeLaging if so, this is a piece of information that should be included in the question; ie., that an agent is running...

Comment: Yes, the other identities were previously loaded.  @jasonwryan, would have included in the question had I known.

Comment: @ChristopherIckes It is a wiki: you can edit your question and include other relevant information...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like ssh is trying all the identities it knows about.  If you want to only try the identity specified in the config file, add the line

```
IdentitiesOnly = yes
```

to that Host section of your .ssh/config file.

Here's the relevant section of the [ssh_config man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config):

> IdentitiesOnly
>   Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the authentication identity files configured in the ssh_config files, even if ssh-agent(1) offers more identities. The argument to this keyword must be ''yes'' or ''no''. This option is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identities. The default is ''no''.